# React when passing query result to next view it's empty

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, navigator

I got a simple aplication with SQLite, i'm trying to pass query result to next view as parameter, but it's always empty.

I got a scrollView Like this with Button and ListView

```
            <TextInput placeholder="Marka" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({brandSearch: text})}/>
            <TextInput placeholder="Model" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({modelSearch: text})}/>
            <Button title="Wyszukaj"
                    color="#841584"
                onPress={() =>
                    navigate('SearchResultView', {data: this.searchCars})
                }
                     /*    onPress={this.searchCars}*/
            />

            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                dataSource={this.state.data}
                renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
                renderRow={(rowData) =>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            fontWeight: "bold"
                        }}>{rowData.brand} {rowData.model} {rowData.power}km {rowData.color}</Text>

                        <Image
                            style={{width: null, height: 200}}
                            source={{uri: rowData.photos}}
                        />
                    </View>
                }
            />

        </ScrollView>
```

And Function to execute

```
searchCars() {
        var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Car;", [], (tx, results) => {
                    var temp = [];
                    var len = results.rows.length;
                    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
                    }

                    resolve(temp);
                });
            });
        });

        p.then((result) => {
             return result;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Your question seems to not be a react specific problem but an issue with how you're handling data. You should provide the implementation of the navigate function and clean up your example into an [mcve] with expected behaviors and such laid out.

Answer (score 0):

Your searchCars method is calling p.then and returning the result within that function call, but p itself isn't being returned. Basically, searchCars isn't returning anything.

```
function wrongSearchCars() {
  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve('hello');
    });

    p.then((result) => {
         return result;
    });
}
function correctSearchCars() {
  var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve('hello');
    });

  return p.then((result) => {
         return result;
  });
}

wrongSearchCars().then(console.log) // undefined
correctSearchCars().then(console.log) // 'hello'
```

Also, as you can see, since the .then block of p inside of searchCars will return a promise, there is no reason to even have that inner call to .then.

```
searchCars() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Car;", [], (tx, results) => {
                var temp = [];
                var len = results.rows.length;
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
                }

                resolve(temp);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

This is my guess based upon what I can see. There's a lot of your code missing that can't be inferred.

Comment: Thanks for help but unfortunately it's still the same, when i log the output it's weird like {"_40":0...}. In the second view it's empty. The whole code is in: https://github.com/MateuszBucko/ReactNativeTemplate/tree/sqliteTask

Comment: In Screens folder there is MainList - main view, SearchResultView - view where i want to navigate with query result, and App.js with navigator. CarDetails you can ignore

Comment: I am also noticing that on line 124 of mainlist file, you are passing searchCars to the navigation method as the value of property 'data.' I'm not too familiar with that module, but judging form the docs, I don't believe it will call the method for you. You probably need to invoke it yourself:

navigate('SearchResultView', {data: this.searchCars()})

Comment: yes, i figured it out, but thanks :), still i can't get real data from sql query it's not returning, thats my bigges problem :(. Now on my first call with setState it's empty, but next is ok..that's weird

Comment: i pused changes..like first call promise not working